# Combine field texts with delimiter in MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to combine texts from table fields with comma delimiter but can't find any function (TEXTJOIN() is available on Excel) like that. So, sample tables looks like-

***Job Table:*** (`JobNo` is number fiels and ***`Primary Key`***)

| JOBNo | JOBDate | CusID | CusName | CusPO | ItemCode | Item | PODate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 443 | 44562 | 4 | UNIT-01 | CO--060637 | FG000038 | HANGER STICKER LLH | 44626 |
| 442 | 44563 | 5 | UNIT-02 | CO--017590 | FG000023 | MAX STICKER | 44626 |
| 441 | 44564 | 5 | UNIT-02 | C0--017591 | FG000023 | MAX STICKER | 44626 |
| 440 | 44565 | 5 | UNIT-02 | CO--17602 | FG000001 | LEG STICKER MAX DUBAI | 44626 |

***Invoice Table:***

| InvoiceNo | InvoiceDate | CusID | CusName | CusPO | JobNo | SalesPerson |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 44577 | 4 | UNIT-01 | PO-000023 | 443 | Mr. Person |
| 2 | 44578 | 4 | UNIT-01 | CO-056449 | 443 | Mr. Person |
| 3 | 44578 | 4 | UNIT-01 | CO-055752 | 443 | Mr. Person |
| 4 | 44578 | 4 | UNIT-01 | CO-054124 | 442 | Mr. Person |
| 5 | 44578 | 4 | UNIT-01 | CO-056717 | 442 | Mr. Person |
| 6 | 44578 | 4 | UNIT-01 | CO-056419 | 441 | Mr. Person |
| 7 | 44578 | 4 | UNIT-01 | CO-056428 | 441 | Mr. Person |
| 8 | 44578 | 4 | UNIT-01 | CO-056357 | 440 | Mr. Person |
| 9 | 44578 | 4 | UNIT-01 | CO-056186 | 440 | Mr. Person |
| 10 | 44578 | 4 | UNIT-01 | CO-54105 | 440 | Mr. Person |
| 11 | 44581 | 4 | UNIT-01 | CO-057137 | 440 | Mr. Person |
| 13 | 44586 | 4 | UNIT-01 | CO-056576 | 442 | Mr. Person |
| 14 | 44586 | 4 | UNIT-01 | CO-056579 | 443 | Mr. Person |
| 15 | 44586 | 4 | UNIT-01 | CO-056580 | 441 | Mr. Person |

***Expected Result:*** (`Invoices` column is combined and expected from above two tables).

| JOBNo | JOBDate | CusID | CusName | CusPO | ItemCode | Item | PODate | Invoices |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 443 | 44562 | 4 | UNIT-01 | CO--060637 | FG000038 | HANGER STICKER LLH | 44626 | 1,2,3,14 |
| 442 | 44563 | 5 | UNIT-02 | CO--017590 | FG000023 | MAX STICKER | 44626 | 4,5,13 |
| 441 | 44564 | 5 | UNIT-02 | C0--017591 | FG000023 | MAX STICKER | 44626 | 6,7,15 |
| 440 | 44565 | 5 | UNIT-02 | CO--17602 | FG000001 | LEG STICKER MAX DUBAI | 44626 | 8,9,10,11 |

Basically I want to aggregate/combine/join each invoice number against `JobNo` in query result. Any help/clue is greatly appreciated.

> I am using MS-Access 365 (16.0... 64 Bit).

Comment: The linked answer (mark as duplicated) works but little bit slower.

Comment: There is no fast way to do it in MS Access.  For every row of the result set, the db engine must run an additional query to gather up the related values which will be concatenated for that row.  It's a substantial workload.